# How to find the folder in a host server with its name starts with a "~"?

Tags: web-hosting, security

For example:

```
http://my-domain/~service
```

In this case, I couldn't find a "~service" folder or file in the server but the url does work, which is very weird.

Comment: That's your home directory

Answer (score 1):

If your web server is running Linux, and you have root access, you can find the folder using the following command:

```
sudo find / -type d -name '~service'
```

If the command returns no results, then the `~` in the URL is most likely referring to the `home` directory, and `service` is most likely referring to a user in the system. You can find this folder here:

```
/home/service
```